# Painless way to track remote Git repo for Wordpress updates

Tags: git, version-control

I'm looking for a way to keep development instances of Wordpress up to date and under version control with Git.

Has anyone managed to the following?

- set up git to track a repo containing the Wordpress core files
- add the Wordpress repo to a project via a submodule or similar
- get the latest version of WP from within the project by updating submodules (or whatever)

Ideally you would just need to update the WP core files in one repository, and then upgrade other dev instances using a single git command.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark Jaquith maintains a git repo of WordPress, synced with the SVN every half hour.

https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress

He also describes how to work with WP in git here:

http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/developing-on-wordpress-using-git/